$\exp(\mathrm{Der}(L)) \subseteq \mathrm{Aut}(L)$ implies $\mathrm{Der}(L) \subseteq \mathrm{Lie}(\mathrm{Aut}(L))$
Let $L$ be a (finite-dimensional real) Lie algebra. Let $\mathrm{Aut}(L) \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(L)$ be the set of all Lie algebra automorphisms on $L$, and let $\mathrm{Der}(L) \subseteq \mathfrak{gl}(L)$ be the Lie subalgebra of derivations on $L$. We have shown in class that $\exp \colon \mathfrak{gl}(L) \to \mathrm{GL}(L)$ sends $\mathrm{Der}(L)$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(L)$. But how does $\mathrm{Der}(L) \subseteq \mathrm{Lie}(\mathrm{Aut}(L))$ follow?
My idea was that $\exp$ restricts to $\mathrm{Der}(L) \to \mathrm{Aut}(L)$. Taking the differential at $0$ gives $\mathrm{Der}(L) \to \mathrm{Lie}(\mathrm{Aut}(L))$, which is a restriction of $d_0 \exp = \mathrm{id}_{\mathfrak{gl}(L)}$. But this argument is not precise enough in my opinion.

Fix a derivation $\phi$. $\gamma:t\mapsto\exp(t\cdot\phi)$ you know, from what was shown in class, is a curve $\Bbb R\to\mathrm{Aut}(L)$, and its derivative is $\phi$ at time zero. Its value at time zero is $\mathrm{Id}$, so $\gamma'(0)\in T_{\mathrm{Id}}(\mathrm{Aut}(L))$; $\phi$ is in the tangent space of the identity, which is the Lie algebra of a Lie group (or canonically identifiable with it, depending on your definitions).
